# Wordpress Permalink Generating 404 Page

Tags: wordpress, post, types

I'm working on changing the permalink of a Custom Post Type to include the taxonomy prior to the post id. I'm capable of it displaying the taxonomy in the URL however when I go to the page I get a 404 Error. It looks like the structure of the permalink is correct however the location of the post isn't synced up w/ the database location.

**Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!**

**Couple of notes:**

- My .htaccess file has mod rewrite on.
- I've added %tax% to the permalink rewrite for the CPT
- I have archive turned on for the CPT

**Code**

```
    function change_permalink( $link, $post ) {
    if ( ‘custom-post-type-name’ == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;
        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, ’taxonomy-name’);
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;

        else $taxonomy_slug = 'no-taxonomy-listed’;

        return str_replace('%tax%', $taxonomy_slug, $link);
    }
    return $link;
    }
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', ‘change_permalink’, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to wp_rewrite:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'urban_permastructure' );
function urban_permastructure($post) {
    if ( 'custom-post-type-name' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $structure = '/cat/%tax%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%tax%", '([^/]+)', "tax-type=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('tax-type', $structure, false);
    }
}
```